# Number of Combinations When the First Value can be More Than the Others

Tags: permutations, combinations

I'm working on a project where we create records in a system and the record ID needs to be random but it needs to have enough combinations to be relatively future proof without making the ID too difficult to remember.

The sticking point for me is that the first value has to be a letter (we will go with either upper or lower case) and the remaining values will be numbers that can repeat.

So for a five value ID for instance the possible values for each character would be 26, 10, 10, 10, 10.  So how many possible combinations are there in that instance?  What about if we went to six or seven?

Answer (score 1):

You have to multiply them, so if you want an id with $n$ characters then the number of ID's is $26\cdot 10^{n-1}.$ So for $5$ would be $26\cdot 10^4=260000.$

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to add up quite right.  If we go to 6 total characters 26 * 10^5 it only goes to 2,600,000.  Shouldn't it be much more?

Comment: Nop. Exactly that many. Why do you think there should be more?

Comment: Take out the 26, you have a number of with $5$ digits, how many of those can you have? Every number before $100000$ Now, you have $26$ copies of those numbers (one copy per letter) so that is how many.

Comment: Doing 10^4 and then 10^5 I would expect to be double but for whatever reason I can't explain, I expected it to more than double due to the first character having 26 possible values.  But doing the math in reverse, 10^5 = 100,000 x 26 = 2,600,000 you're correct.  Besides that, not using a permutation formula to get to the answer threw me off as well.

Comment: Permutations are used when you do not allow repetitions. Here you allow any kind of repetition, so the product rule is enough. Well $10^5/10^4=10$ is it more than double! It is $10$ times higher